# Yii: custom error handling forwarding

Tags: php, yii, error-handling

I'm looking for a way to *forward* the error handling in my Yii 1.1.14 app. The scenario comes as follows:

Assuming I have two modules: ClientModule at /client/, AdminModule at /admin/. If an url is resolved to belong to any controller in that module, the controller is loaded, and the errorHandler is reassigned to a module-level error handler like this:

```
public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)
{
    Yii::app()->errorHandler->errorAction='admin/error';
    return parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action);
}
```

In this way, an action exists at 'admin/admin/error' (which in turn is manually specified to be resolved to 'admin/error'), which will handle the error with a boilerplate like:

```
public function actionError() {
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('application.views.error.index', $error);
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the analogous code (for both functions) exist in the other module (There's also a ClientModule and a ClientController with an actionError mapped automatically to 'client/client/error', remapped to 'client/error').

I have no trouble at all with these code chunks. **My issue starts now**:

If I input an url which cannot be resolved, even when the prefix is a module prefix (e.g. 'client/invalid/url' or 'client/client/invalid'), the controller will not be created (since it does not exist - or, as in the second example, the controller exists but not the action), and so `beforeController` will not be called, and so the custom error handler (in this example: the corresponding to ClientModule which sets $aClientController->actionError) will not be assigned. Result: the default ErrorController handling the unresolved url error.

So, **questions**:

1. Is there any way I could map an unresolved url (404) error to certain module, depending on the prefix? (it is safe, in my case, to assume prefixes, since I have not set any module as default).
2. Alternatively: is there a way to, being in the ErrorController->actionIndex(), forward the error handling to one of those controllers (i.e. moving to admin/admin/error and client/client/error while keeping the `Yii::app()->errorHandler->error` state)?

Edit - **Footnote**: Why should I use another controller if the error handling code is the same? Because I have additional data provided by those controllers which is used in the layout (e.g. menu, head menu).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, again (my juniority has no limits - **and the method name I needed had the exact name: forward!!**).

Using the `CController->forward('module/controller/action')` inside the `ErrorController->actionError` method I could dispatch everywhere. I also changed another business logic condition and have not the custom error handler assignment in the modules constructors anymore, but I still use those controllers as forward targets of 'error/index' depending on the logged user type (i.e. an error occurred and the user was a client => forward to client/client/error, while being admin led to admin/admin/error, and being no logged user performed the error handling with error/index as usual).

```
public function actionIndex() {
    if (Yii::app()->user->getState('client'))
    {
        $this->forward('client/client/error');
    }
    if (Yii::app()->user->getState('staff'))
    {
        $this->forward('admin/admin/error');
    }

    //usual boilerplate here
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('index', $error);
    }
}
```